# I got an error in the wrong order in the truth table in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here, I have:

Infix: R|(P&Q) and I converted it to Postfix: RPQ&|

I have the code make the table from Postfix

while True:

```
x = input("\n\nEnter Calculation: ").upper()

vars = []
for i in x:
    print(i,end=' ')
    if i.isalpha() and not i in vars:
        vars.append(i)

for i in range(2**len(vars)):
    print('')
    string = bin(i)[2:].rjust(len(vars),'0')
    bools = list(map((lambda x: True if x=='1' else False), string))
    a = dict(zip(vars,bools))
    math = []
    for j in x:
        if j.isalpha():
            math.append(a[j])
            print(int(a[j]),end=' ')
        elif j == '&':
            math[-2] = math[-2] & math[-1]
            print(int(math[-2]),end=' ')
            del math[-1]
        elif j == '|':
            math[-2] = math[-2] | math[-1]
            print(int(math[-2]),end=' ')
            del math[-1]
        elif j == '^':
            math[-2] = math[-2] ^ math[-1]
            print(int(math[-2]),end=' ')
            del math[-1]
        elif j == '>':
            math[-2] = math[-2] <= math[-1]
            print(int(math[-2]),end=' ')
            del math[-1]
        elif j == '<':
            math[-2] = math[-2] >= math[-1]
            print(int(math[-2]),end=' ')
            del math[-1]
        elif j == '!' or j == '~' or j == '`':
            math[-1] = not math[-1]
            print(int(math[-1]),end=' ')
        else:
            print("Error: Invalid Character")
```

Input: RPQ&|

Output:

Enter Calculation: RPQ&|

R P Q & |

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 0

0 1 0 0 0

0 1 1 1 1

1 0 0 0 1

1 0 1 0 1

1 1 0 0 1

1 1 1 1 1

But it's wrong. Because the real answer should be:

P Q R & |

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 1 0 1

0 1 0 0 0

0 1 1 0 1

1 0 0 0 0

1 0 1 0 1

1 1 0 1 1

1 1 1 1 1

I need help. It is out of order P Q R. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong. The two answers are the same. The only difference is the variables' order

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how to fix the code like answer 2 ?